# Changing windows service display name?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, services

I would like to change the display name of a windows service that has already been created.  I have read online that I can just alter the value in the registry.  If I alter it in the registry and then relaunch my services window, the new name does not seem to be reflected.  I assume if I restart my computer this new name will be reflected but I need a solution that will show up immediately with out having to restart my computer.

Here is an example:

I launch services.exe and right-click on the service I want to change and click properties.  In the properties window I see the service name as `service1` and the display name as `service1`.  I go into the registry and navigate to

`HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\services\service1`.

In here there is a field called `DisplayName` that is set to `service1`.  I go and change this value to `Some Name`.  After changing this value I relaunch services and I still see `service1`.  When I go to properties of `service1`, I still see the display name as `service1` and not `Some Name`.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? What Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this with the `SC` command. For example, to rename the **Themes** service to **Theme Manager**, open a command prompt with administrator rights. Type

```
sc config Themes DisplayName= "Theme Manager"
```

Note the space between the equal sign and the new name. This is mandatory.

If you refresh the services console, you'll see the change. No need to reboot beforehand.

Comment: It seemed like everywhere I looked, people were saying the SC command could not change the display name of a service so I never went and actually looked at the sc command closer.  But, this command worked with flying colors!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Seconded. This works great!

Comment: *As a side note for others:* if the new name contains spaces, it is also mandatory to **enclose it in parenthesis** (like in the example above), otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Note, this does NOT change the names "sc" uses for future commands. Rather, it only changes how it appears in Services gui. To change the name to use with "sc", use the regedit technique described by @Nikola-Dimitrijevic

Comment: @macetw Not sure what you mean. It changes the display name of the service, which is what the question was about. The service name is something else entirely.

Comment: WIN10Pro 1809: it does not work. see comment in post below.

Answer (score 3):

Even you were close you have done it wrong. :)

First navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`
In the **LEFT** pane, select the Service key you want to rename, press <kbd>F2</kbd>
and enter the name you want

If you have **enum** subkey when you expand main key, just delete it as it will be recreated upon restart

[image]

The DisplayName subkey can be changed, but you dont have to do that. Usually you will change it to follow the changed Service name

Now restart the computer

Comment: WIN10Pro 1809: you must change the DisplayName key on the right, otherwise the displayname in "services" app is not changed.